# Set a docker registry behind Apache proxy

Tags: docker, apache, virtual-machine, registry, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set up a private docker registry behind Apache Proxy (name: xxx.org). The machine for the docker registry is a Virtual Machine running on centos 8 (hostname: dockerhub), different from the Apache server machine but on the same network and I can reach from Apache machine (through ping or ssl for example).
**But I can't reach my docker registry**.

I followed the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#run-a-local-registry
I deployed this registry on dockerhub VM:

> docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
> -v "$(pwd)"/certs:/certs -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt -e
> REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key

With this apache ssl config (on xxx.org machine):

> ProxyPass /dockerhub http://dockerhub:5000/v2 Keepalive=On

> ProxyPassReverse /dockerhub http://dockerhub:5000/v2

The port 5000 in dockerhub VM is open (it's working for a simple registry as described in the doc) and I have had these settings on sytemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf

> [Service] Environment="NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,dockerhub"

The port 443 is working on Apache machine(I do other redirections).
But I can't push basic image like that :
docker push xxx.org/dockerhub/ubuntu:16.04
I have a retrying loop and the end message:

> received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error

I'm really confused and I reaaly don't know where is the error: ProxyPass? Docker Registry?
Thanks